# Regex to match strings in-between double quotes that are not containing some other strings

Tags: java, regex

How to match words between double quotes in lines not containing specific words

input:

- System.log("error");
- new Exception("error");
- view.setText("message");

From the above input, I would like to ignore lines with `log` and `Exception` words in them(Case sensitive) and match words in between double quotes.

Expected output

- message

I have been trying to use look ahead without luck

```
(?s)^(?!log)".+"
```

I need this for a search in IntelliJ using regex

Comment: `^.*(?<!(log)|(xception))\(".+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern `(?s)^(?!log)".+"` the negative lookahead does not contain a quantifier so it will assert that what is directly after the start of the string is not `log`

What you could do is use a quantifier `.*` with an alternation to match either `log` or `Exception` and add word boundaries `\b` to prevent them being part of a larger word.

Then you might use negated character classes `[^"]` to match not a double quote and use a capturing group `([^"]+)`  for the value between the double quotes.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:log|Exception)\b)[^"]*"([^"]+)"
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "^(?!.*\\b(?:log|Exception)\\b)[^\"]*\"([^\"]+)\"";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/65zg9v/1)

If you want to make the dot to match a newline you can prepend `(?s)` to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression would likely work for capturing the `message`,

```
^(?!.*log.*|.*exception.*).*?"(.+?)".*
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/t5cQkz/1)

#### Example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?!.*log.*|.*exception.*).*?"(.+?)".*";
final String string = "System.log(\"error\");\n"
     + "new Exception(\"error\");\n"
     + "view.setText(\"message\");";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```